# How to pass data from Controller to Blade Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i've been searching the cause of my error. So basicly i want to pass data from Controller to Blade using Compact but turns out the data is sent, but the blade won't read the data, instead it just print like normal print html. Please help me.

This is the controller

```html
    public function detailproduk($id){
        $produk = Produk::all();
        $produk2= Produk::where('id', $id)->first();
        $data = "IPHONE";
        $pro2 = Produk::where('id', $id)->first();


        //dd($produk2);
        return view('homepage/detailproduk', compact('produk2'));
    }
```

this is the blade

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Product Detail</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('css/detailproduk.css')?>" type="text/css"> 
  </head>

  <body>
      
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="container-fliud">
                <div class="wrapper row">
                    
                    <div class="preview col-md-6">
                        
                        <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
                        <br>
                          <div class="tab-pane active" id="pic-1"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/252" /></div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="details col-md-6">
                        <h3 class="product-title">{{$pro2->produk_name}}</h3>
                        <div class="rating">
                            <div class="stars">
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="review-no">{{$produk2->product_rate}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="product-description">{{$produk2->description}}</p>
                        <h4 class="price">current price: <span>{{$produk2->price}}</span></h4>
                        <p class="vote"><strong>91%</strong> of buyers enjoyed this product! <strong>(87 votes)</strong></p>
                        <h5 class="sizes">Stock:
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="small">{{$produk2->stock}}</span>
                        </h5>
                        <h5 class="colors">colors:
                            <span class="color orange not-available" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not In store"></span>
                            <span class="color green"></span>
                            <span class="color blue"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <div class="action">
                            <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-default" type="button">Buy Now</button>
                            <button class="like btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span> Add to Chart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the result is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe49G.png)

Comment: can you confirm you named your file with `.blade.php`: detailproduk.blade.php

Comment: hi efraim, welcome to stackoverflow. your `$pro2->produk_name` should be failing already as no variable with name `$pro2` is sent. where is this `blade` file located and is it named properly?

Answer (score -2):

When received compact data in blade file, you need to use loop for retrieving data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).